# How can I use the same functions on two separated (but similar) elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wrote jQuery functions that show/hide divs by switching classes. The code below is basically working. What I can't manage to do is to control each div separately. Clicking on the second group of divs will trigger the 1st one. How could I distinguish each of the elements and make the same functions work for both groups independently?

```js
function _open() {
  var nextDiv = $("#sub_container").find("[class]").map(function() {
    return this.className;
  }).get();
  $.unique(nextDiv).forEach(function(c) {
    $('.' + c).first().removeClass('close').addClass('open');
  });
}

function _close() {
  $('.open').not('.close').each(function(key, elm) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      $(elm).removeClass('open').addClass('close');
    }, key * 100);
  });
}
```

```css
.container {
  float: left;
  display: inline;
}

.starter {
  display: block;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  color: white;
}

.open {
  display: block;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  color: white;
}

.close {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="project1" class="container">
  <div class="starter" onclick="_open();">Each click will show a new div</div>
  <div id="sub_container">
    <div class="close">1</div>
    <div class="close">2</div>
    <div class="close">3<br><br><button onclick="_close();">click here to hide all divs</button></div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="project2" class="container">
  <div class="starter" onclick="_open();">Each click will show a new div</div>
  <div id="sub_container">
    <div class="close"></div>
    <div class="close"></div>
    <div class="close"><button onclick="_close();">click here to hide all divs</button></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Instead of using inline events like `onclick`, consider using [event handlers](https://learn.jquery.com/events/handling-events/). After implementing them, you can use `$(this)` to refer specifically to *"the clicked element"*, or `$("selector").not(this)` to make it an exception.

Comment: When you "open" an element, you want *only* that element to open, but if you click "close" all open elements are closed - is that your intended functionality?

Comment: @OP you simply haven't looked at all the available tools in the toolbox. Like closest(), parent(), find(), etc.

Comment: @wahwahwah Yes it is. What is bothering me is when I click on the right red div from #project2, it's triggering an action on the #project1 children. Do you see me on this one?

Comment: @ChrisG You're absolutely right. The thing is that I've no clue which one I should use to get this going. What would you do?

Comment: @TylerRoper Thx Tyler. Not sure to perfectly follow though. How would you write it exactly?

Comment: @AlexisVey I'd probably read the documentation, experiment, do basic debugging and so on.

Comment: @TylerRoper lol thx for this input. Basically: "I wouldn't show the world my weaknesses because people might laugh and struggle with this few lines of code". I guess the StackOverflow community is not meant to help people get things done :-)

Comment: @AlexisVey Not sure what that means, perhaps I was accidentally mentioned. In any case, the resource I've linked in my original comment should help you with how to write them.

Answer (score 0):

One issue in your code is that you have two divs with the id `sub_container` in HTML, IDs shouldn't be reused on the same page, they are meant to be a unique identifier for a single element.

However, just changing this on its own won't solve your problem :)

`$("#sub_container")` is too generic, it searches the entire DOM for an element with this ID, but what you want to do is search within the group of the div you just clicked. You could do this using `siblings`. I've updated the demo you posted to do this.

A few changes had to be made.

First we need to know which element was clicked. To do this I updated the link `onclick="_open()"` to `onclick="_open(event)"` This passes the click event when it is called and we can use that to figure out which element was clicked. (You could also use `this` to simply pass the element but since most commonly you see events being passed around I opted to go with this)

Next we need to find the relevant sub container. That is this line:

`var $subContianer = $(e.currentTarget).siblings(".sub_container");`

I am using the event's currentTarget (eg the element bound on for the click) and then searching for a sibling with the class `sub_container`

To be honest your next bit of code seemed odd to me but I left it in place as-is. I think it could be done much more simply though. However I updated it to use `$subcontainer.find` to search for the divs to open instead of a generic `$(selector)` (for the same "too generic" reasons as before)

I didn't update the close code, I thought it would be a good exercise for you to try these principles out and figure out that bit on your own :)

Good luck!

```js
function _open(e) {
  var $subContianer = $(e.currentTarget).siblings(".sub_container");
  var nextDiv = $subContianer.find("[class]").map(function() {
    return this.className;
  }).get();
  
  $.unique(nextDiv).forEach(function(c) {
     $subContianer.find('.' + c).first().removeClass('close').addClass('open');
  });
}

function _close() {
  $('.open').not('.close').each(function(key, elm) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      $(elm).removeClass('open').addClass('close');
    }, key * 100);
  });
}
```

```css
.container {
  float: left;
  display: inline;
}

.starter {
  display: block;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  color: white;
}

.open {
  display: block;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  color: white;
}

.close {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="project1" class="container">
  <div class="starter" onclick="_open(event);">Each click will show a new div</div>
  <div class="sub_container">
    <div class="close">1</div>
    <div class="close">2</div>
    <div class="close">3<br><br><button onclick="_close();">click here to hide all divs</button></div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="project2" class="container">
  <div class="starter" onclick="_open(event);">Each click will show a new div</div>
  <div class="sub_container">
    <div class="close"></div>
    <div class="close"></div>
    <div class="close"><button onclick="_close();">click here to hide all divs</button></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

In short:

- Pass around `event` so you can tell where a click originated
- Instead of searching the entire DOM via `$('selector here')` make it more specific by finding the element you want to search from and then using `.find`

Documentation on some of this stuff:
http://api.jquery.com/find/
https://api.jquery.com/siblings/